# UWP Generating a PDF - best approach

Tags: xaml, pdf, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app and as one of the requirements I need to generate a PDF file dynamically.

There are a few contraints / requirements that I need to concider:

- Need an ability to generate PDF from the UWP app directly / offline scenario
- Potentially need an ability to generate the report on the server - ideally from the same source template
- Report needs to be somewhat dynamic (i.e. not compiled into the app it self and format editable without recompilation of the app)
- Ideally - not depend on a closed source propetiary library / component

I have had couple of ideas on how to approach this:

1. Have a XAML page and convert it PDF by printing that XAML view as a PDF through a hidden print dialog - limited by the fact the XAML will need to be compiled into the app + would probably be imposisble to use the same approach to generate reports on the server side.
2. Do something similar with an WebView and HTML - but that will require JavaScript logic to be executed - adn I'm not sure if it is possible in UWP app.

Has anyone achieved something similar in the past and if so - what approach have you taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there are many third party paid packages for generating PDF in UWP, such as [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and [XFinium](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html). For free libraries like [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) that are not available in UWP. Since you don't want a paid one, you may consider to create classical application with free libraries and then create an AppService to handle it. For more details please reference [AppServiceBridgeSample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample).

> Have a XAML page and convert it PDF by printing

Generate the PDF by [printing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) feature  can work well. But for your requirements "through a hidden print dialog" is not possible, print UI cannot be hidden to print.

> Do something similar with an WebView and HTML

The open [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library can help you generate HTML to PDF by JavaScript. And you can get the PDF result return by  [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) from `WebView`. For example:

JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
        function print() {
            var doc = new jsPDF()
            doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
            doc.circle(50, 50, 50);
            var pdfresult = doc.output(); 
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText = pdfresult; 
            //doc.save('a4.pdf');
            return pdfresult;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myDiv'>Hello</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

WebView

```
Webview.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/test.html"));
string pdfresult = await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "print()" });
StorageFile pdf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.pdf");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(pdf, pdfresult);
```

After all, you can consider Write the PDF file format yourself. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c/) is a document for windows phone but you may still reference.

Comment: what if we want to insert an imagefile in that pdf as well?

Comment: Ended up going with Syncfusion components.

Comment: @SunteenWu Your code seems promising but it creates `test.pdf` of size `0kb` in local folder. I even added lots of test to the `test.html` file to make it of a size 8kb. But the resulting `test.pdf` file is still empty (`0kb` size).

Comment: I don't know when support was added, but there is a [PdfSharpCore Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharpCore).  It works for me with no bridge app necessary.