# HTML to PDF support for UWP

Tags: uwp, wkhtmltopdf

Does anyone know wkhtmltopdf support on UWP platform?
Something like WkHtmlToXSharp but for UWP?

Comment: Already asked, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009600/html-to-pdf-in-a-windows-universal-app-uwp

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know wkhtmltopdf support on UWP platform?

`wkhtmltopdf` is a command line tool, by testing on my side, it can work well on windows 10 platform by command line. My windows 10 OS build is 15063.
[image]

> Something like WkHtmlToXSharp but for UWP?

If you are trying to find packages that generate PDF for UWP app, currently, there are many third party paid packages for generating PDF in UWP, such as [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and [XFinium](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html). For free libraries like [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)  may not available in UWP. If you don't want a paid package you may try the follows:

- Using [printing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) feature in UWP. With a virtual PDF print drive to print HTML as PDF.
- Using a [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) to combine with [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library. Details for how to do you may reference [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496324/uwp-generating-a-pdf-best-approach).
- Write your own PDF library by reference [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c/) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009600/html-to-pdf-in-a-windows-universal-app-uwp).